# C# How to translate virtual keycode to char?

Tags: c#, char, converters, keycode

I am trying to map a virtual keycode to a char.

My code uses ProcessCmdKey to listen to WM_KEYDOWN which gives me access to the key pressed. For example, when I press single quote I get a key of 222 which I want to have it mapped to keychar 39 which represents... you guessed it... single quote.

My dev context is:
- .net Framework 2.0
- UserControl placed in a lot of places

Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306(VS.85).aspx)() ?

Answer (score 48):

Isn't that what the [System.Windows.Form.KeysConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter.aspx) class is for?

```
KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
string keyChar = kc.ConvertToString(keyData);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the context of my question:
- .net Framework 2.0
- UserControl

So the answer to your answer is no.

Comment: Just noticed I never replied to that... [KeysConverter exists in .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Hm, but that works only partially. As an example where it won't work: `(new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(Keys.OemQuestion)` *(**Spoiler:** it would return `OemQuestion` instead of `?`)*. Besides, it isn't clear how to handle *Shift* key. Is there a working solution?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Make sure you're matching the correct KeysConverter to the correct Keys enum.   [System.Windows.Forms.KeyConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.converttostring.aspx) is for WinForms, [System.Windows.Input.KeyConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.aspx) is for WPF.

Comment: As for modifier keys, the Keys enum actually consists of flags, so D would actually be `Keys.Shift | Keys.D`

Comment: Real answer (at least for me and I guess for some more), is [further below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38787314/568266).

Comment: Nah, this is just the same with the Keys.ToString()

Answer (score 29):

Yes, I did use the `MapVirtualKey` method. But I was expecting more details on how to use it: what `DllImport` directive to use, what `enum` is specific for mapping to characters, etc.

I don't like these answers where you google for like 5 seconds and then just suggest a solution: the real challenge is to put all the pieces together and not have to waste your time with tons of sample-less MSDN pages or other coding forums in order to get your answer. No offense plinth, but your answer (even good) was worhtless since I had this answer even before posting my question on the forum!

So there you  go, I am going to post what I was looking for - an out-of-the-box C# solution:

1- Place this directive inside your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
```

2- Retrieve your char like this:

```
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)      
  {
     const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

     if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
     {            
        // 2 is used to translate into an unshifted character value 
        int nonVirtualKey = MapVirtualKey((uint)keyData, 2);

        char mappedChar = Convert.ToChar(nonVirtualKey);
     }

     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }
```

Thanks for caring... and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for following up.  If you had already looked at MapVirtualKey() perhaps you should've included that in your question (ie, "I've looked at MapVirtualKey() but I don't know how to call it from C#).  For your future needs, you might find http://www.pinvoke.net useful.

Comment: And in the case of MapVirtualKey, here's the entry from pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MapVirtualKey.html

Comment: Minor correction: MapVirtualKey actually returns a uint, not an int. But thank you for that bit of code, it was exactly what I needed for my own project.

Comment: Very helpful Q&A. I was searching for this. Thank you.

Comment: THIS should be the top-voted answer. The currently top-voted doesn't for for chars that aren't alphanumeric.

Answer (score 25):

I was looking for something similar but I needed the character mapped to the current keyboard layout. Since none of the above answers fulfilled my requirements, here is what I came up with.

```
        public string KeyCodeToUnicode(Keys key)
        {
            byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];
            bool keyboardStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

            if (!keyboardStateStatus)
            {
                return "";
            }

            uint virtualKeyCode = (uint)key;
            uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(virtualKeyCode, 0);
            IntPtr inputLocaleIdentifier = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            ToUnicodeEx(virtualKeyCode, scanCode, keyboardState, result, (int)5, (uint)0, inputLocaleIdentifier);

            return result.ToString();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);
```

Comment: Excellent. It works perfectly with non English characters. I use it from KeyDown event and call it with e.Keycode or e.KeyData and both works. Thanks

Comment: The hero we need, but not the hero we deserve!

Comment: This is great. Works as expected.
On the other side, such an obvious task require a lot of code. Well done.

Comment: I noticed unexpected results when holding a modifier-key while calling the function and started wondering... Why get the current keyboard state? Works as expected whithout the part related to current keyboard state - and I don't see why the current state would be relevant anyway... am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like this was lifted (without attribution) from PInvoke.net (https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.tounicodeex)

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy given the "quality" articles http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.hello%20from%20spws and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.how%20to%20suck%20cock%20on%20today on pinvoke.net, it's probably safe to say the lifting was done the other way around.

Comment: So which is safer for Me to *Lift* into my own code (with attribution, of course): `byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];` from this answer or `byte[] bKeyState = new byte[256];` from pinvoke.net?

Comment: `new byte[255]` or `new byte[256]' ? See [nf-winuser-tounicodeex on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) for the answer.

Comment: Yes, as @gridtrak has figured it out, the [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) article shows that codes go from 0x01 to 0xFE or from 1 to 255.

Answer (score 7):

After reading and testing some of the answers provided, I thought I'd suggest an alternative.

As mentioned by [MM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195849/mm), System.Windows.KeysConverter does not provide a character representation of the key but rather the enum's name, e.g. "Enter" instead of '\n'.

The MapVirtualKey method suggested by [Horas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12333/horas), in answer to his own question, is a good starting point, but still does not support either capslock, or characters entered with the shift key, e.g. '!', '$' and '>'.

An alternative to the MapVirtualKey method, that I am using, is an extension method for the Keys class:

```cs
public static char ToChar(this Keys key)
{
    char c = '\0';
    if((key >= Keys.A) && (key <= Keys.Z))
    {
        c = (char)((int)'a' + (int)(key - Keys.A));
    }

    else if((key >= Keys.D0) && (key <= Keys.D9))
    {
        c = (char)((int)'0' + (int)(key - Keys.D0));
    }

    return c;
}
```

The method shown above will provide support for alphanumeric characters. Support for additional characters could be implemented with either a switch statement or lookup table.

Comment: Does this use `System.Windows.Forms` or `System.Windows.Input`? `Key` is an enumeration in `System.Windows.Input`, but is not used here, and it is unclear where `Keys` comes from.

Comment: 'Keys' is part of 'System.Windows.Forms'

Answer (score 6):

I've just written an improvement of [Ivan Petrov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char/38787314#38787314) to display a string representation of pressed key combinations in WPF, see my code below:

```cs
public static string GetKeyString(Key key, ModifierKeys modifiers)
{
    string result = "";
    if (key != Key.None)
    {
        // Setup modifiers
        if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
            result += "Ctrl + ";
        if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
            result += "Alt + ";
        if (modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
            result += "Shift + ";
        // Get string representation
        string keyStr = key.ToString();
        int keyInt = (int)key;
        // Numeric keys are returned without the 'D'
        if (key >= Key.D0 && key <= Key.D9)
            keyStr = char.ToString((char)(key - Key.D0 + '0'));
        // Char keys are returned directly
        else if (key >= Key.A && key <= Key.Z)
            keyStr = char.ToString((char)(key - Key.A + 'A'));
        // If the key is a keypad operation (Add, Multiply, ...) or an 'Oem' key, P/Invoke
        else if ((keyInt >= 84 && keyInt <= 89) || keyInt >= 140)
            keyStr = KeyCodeToUnicode(key);
        result += keyStr;
    }
    return result;
}

private static string KeyCodeToUnicode(Key key)
{
    byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];
    bool keyboardStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

    if (!keyboardStateStatus)
    {
        return "";
    }

    uint virtualKeyCode = (uint)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);
    uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(virtualKeyCode, 0);
    IntPtr inputLocaleIdentifier = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    ToUnicodeEx(virtualKeyCode, scanCode, new byte[255], result, (int)5, (uint)0, inputLocaleIdentifier);

    return result.ToString();
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);
```

Comment: Hmm, this works, but if a non-alphanumeric keys is pressed, the return result is an empty string. Similarly, if the user presses `space` or `TAB`, the result will be *invisible*, making the user think that no result was returned. 

Is there a list somewhere of non-alphanumeric key codes and their corresponding names so that we can return the name of the key pressed?

Comment: Maybe put more conditions in the `GetKeyString` method.

Answer (score 1):

KeysConverter gets the key name not the keys "text"
ex: "Num2" instead of "2"
MapVirtualKey will work for english but for non-english chars documentation states using MapVirtualKeyEx but that requires a locale Identifier
that identifier is loaded by LoadKeyBoardLayout which requires a culture id constant
but then after finding the correct id values it didn't work as i tried it so finally i dumped the whole thing

Comment: MapVirtualKey works also for non-english layouts. it uses the actual keyboard-layout.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WPF (I didn't try it with WinForms), there is a very simple solution that returns directly the pressed char, the [TextInput Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.textinput?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.TextInput);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) of Window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextInput += MainWindow_TextInput;
    }

    private void MainWindow_TextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text += e.Text;
    }
}
```