# Filter control keys from KeyEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a small event handler to process all keys pressed by the user or delivered by barcode scanner:

```
public void KeyDownSink(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _textRead.Append(e.Key);
}

private StringBuilder _textRead = new StringBuilder();
```

The variable `_textRead` should collect all characters pressed. I'm only interested in keys which produce a printable output (a-z,0-9, !"§$%& and so on). If the user presses e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> this will add the string *LeftCtrl* to `_textRead`, so I want to skip this key.

**How to filter out control keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, , <kbd>Alt</kbd>... in an elegant way?**

I know I can achieve this with a lot of conditional statements (`if e.Key == Key.Ctrl`) but I hope to find a nicer way.

Comment: Can you not check it as `char.IsNumber` `char.IsLetter` just convert the key to char and only allow for the two conditions

Comment: @V4Vendetta: But how to convert the `Key` enumeration to a `char`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Input;

public void KeyDownSink(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)   
{  
    string keyPressed = _keyConv.ConvertToString(e.Key);

    if (keyPressed != null && keyPressed.Length == 1) 
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(keyPressed[0]))
        {
            _textRead.Append(keyPressed[0]);
        }
    }
}

private StringBuilder _textRead = new StringBuilder();   
private KeyConverter _keyConv = new KeyConverter();
```

Comment: Just checked some more answers about this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826175/913577). This gets way to complicated, I think I just stick with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this questions for KeyEventArgs filtering. Since this is bold in the question I'd like to add the answer for that question

**Filtering out modifiers**

```
public void KeyDownSink(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)  {
        var pressedModifiers = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers;
        if (pressedModifiers != ModifierKeys.None) return;

        //do your stuff
}
```

this will filter out combinations such as Ctrl+a

**Filtering out specific modifiers**

```
public void KeyDownSink(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)  {
        List<Key> ExitKeys = new List<Key> { Key.LeftCtrl, Key.RightCtrl, Key.LeftAlt, Key.RightAlt, Key.LeftShift, Key.RightShift };
        if (ExitKeys.contains(e.Key)) return;

        //do your stuff
}
```