# From an OnKeyDown override, can you programmatically determine the character which would be displayed (if any) from its corresponding e.Key value?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keycode, onkeydown

On different machines, in an `OnKeyDown` override, the `e.Key` values are not necessarily consistent.  For instance, on my Mac running Win7-64 under Boot Camp, the backslash key is reported as `Key.OemQuote` and not `Key.OemBackslash` as one would expect, which makes no sense considering that's not even on the same key.  On a co-worker's Dell, it's reported as something else entirely.

However, in both cases, the correct backslash character is appearing in a textbox when typing so the OS obviously somehow knows that's what character that key is tied to.

We're trying to determine if, given a keycode on a particular system, you can get the corresponding character, if any, which that key represents (assuming no modifiers are pressed.)

Note: I am already aware of the `OnPreviewTextInput` and `OnTextInput` events which deal with the characters that are typed, but that is *not* what I am asking.

I am *specifically* asking about a function that takes a KeyCode as a parameter and returns what character would be displayed on-screen if that key were to be pressed.

For instance, on my machine, the function would take `Key.OemQuote` and would return the backslash character.  Passing in `Key.Control` would return `null` (since nothing actually appears when Control is pressed alone.)

Note: I've put up another question about dealing with the different key codes specifically that may look similar to this question, but this is a very specific separate question relating to a function that takes such a code and returns a character, so please do not mark this as a duplicate. It is not.

Comment: I think [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826175/1069200) have figured it out. All my tests using his code passed, dont know about on a Mac.

Comment: Put that in an answer, instead of a comment, and if it works, I'll mark yours as the accepted one.  Looks like it will.  Hate pinvoking, but it does seem to be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826175/1069200) applies.

Also check out [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx)
[PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mapvirtualkey)