# IsLetter on DataGrid KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, char, keydown

I am attempting to break down user input onto a KeyDown event on a DataGrid by working out whether their input is a letter or a number. This is the method I am using so far;

```
private void OnDataGridKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Letter");
    }
    if (char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Number");
    }
}
```

However, this performs bizzarely. Firstly, the IsDigit never happens and clearly is not working. Secondly the IsLetter works, but only on some letters (W,Z,X,V and Y). There must be a more comprehensive way of doing this as this clearly is not working for me.

Comment: You should log `Convert.ToChar(e.Key))`

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between `key.toChar()` and `char` which you expect to be there. You can read about conversion here but it's not simple one:

[how to capture the '#' character on different locale keyboards in WPF/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825820/how-to-capture-the-character-on-different-locale-keyboards-in-wpf-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @thomas-ayoub added how to use it in current context

Comment: Why would one re-implement `char.IsLetter()` and `char.IsDigit()` when it already exists and works well?

Comment: You right bro, there is another problen in that question

Comment: `char.IsLetter(Convert.ToChar(Keys.A))  => true` this **should** work, without more information from OP, there is no way to help

Comment: The main problem here is that the event he's are catching is keyboard event and that the key is indeed a key and NOT a character. For example, when typing shift-A, you will receive two event instead of one for keypressed.

Comment: And the event handling `Shift` will not log anything while the event handling `A` should log *Letter*. Let's wait for OP