# WPF TextBox input filtering doesn't work as expected with a decimal

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, input, textbox

I am trying to filter the input to a WPF `TextBox` to prevent the user from entering non-numerical strings. I have configured `PreviewKeyDown` and am checking the characters entered with the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825820/how-to-capture-the-character-on-different-locale-keyboards-in-wpf-c) to convert the key codes to characters. Everything works as expected except when the user enters a period. The code does detect a period was entered, yet when I return from `PreviewKeyDown` with setting `KeyEventArgs`'s `Handled` to false, it doesn't allow the period to be entered.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource SomeObject}" Path="SomePath" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MyValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char character = GetCharFromKey(e.Key);

    e.Handled = false;
    if (character >= '0' && character <= '9')
        return;
    if (character == '.')
        return;
    switch(e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Delete:
        case Key.Back:
            return;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove your ValidationRule or post the code for it...your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Even with `<Binding.ValidationRules> <local:MyValidationRule/> </Binding.ValidationRules>` removed this still occurs, so the rule can be easily ruled out as the cause. It only seems to not occur when `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` is removed, with or without the `Binding.ValidationRules`.

Comment: What type is SomePath? You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The type is `Decimal`

Comment: You can't set a decimal to something like "3.".

Comment: It looks like you're right. But I would think you should be able to set a decimal to something like "3.". Although the compiler wont allow you to, `Convert.ToDecimal("1234.")` works just fine as does `Decimal.TryParse("1234.", out myDecimal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you handle the `PreviewTextInput` event? Something like this:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    string str = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;
    decimal i;
    e.Handled = !decimal.TryParse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomePath}" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
```

**Edit:** The problem with using a an `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `PropertyChanged` is that the string "5." gets converted to `5M` and that's the value that you see in the `TextBox`. The "5." string is not stored somewhere.

You could possible overcome this by using a converter that keeps track of the latest known string:

```
public class DecimalToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string _lastConvertedValue;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return _lastConvertedValue ?? value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value?.ToString();
        decimal d;
        if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
        {
            _lastConvertedValue = str;
            return d;
        }

        _lastConvertedValue = null;
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SomePath" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:DecimalToStringConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Nope, still wont allow a period.

Comment: It does if you remove the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute. "5." gets converted to 5M and that's the value that you see in the TextBox when using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. The "5." string is not stored somewhere...

Comment: @Matt: You may be able to use a converter. See my edit.

Comment: I'll give it a try later on, if not i'll just add a string property to `SomeObject`, bind to that, and in its setter, just do a Convert.ToDecimal and set the decimal property. But since you've spent so much effort on this I feel compelled to accept your answer anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a behaviour I use for this, I think it's based on something I got off the web. You could just use it as is, or work out why your version isn't working.  Note the code handles pasting in though.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace UILib
{
    public class TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        public string EmptyValue { get; set; } = "0";

        public double Minimum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


        public double Maximum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));



        public int MaxInteger
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxIntegerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxIntegerProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxIntegerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxInteger", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(1));



        public int MaxDecimals
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxDecimalsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxDecimalsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxDecimalsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxDecimals", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(2));



        /// <summary>
        ///     Attach our behaviour. Add event handlers
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += PreviewTextInputHandler;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += PreviewKeyDownHandler;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Deattach our behaviour. remove event handlers
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= PreviewTextInputHandler;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= PreviewKeyDownHandler;
            DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, PastingHandler);
        }

        void PreviewTextInputHandler(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            string text;
            if (this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length < this.AssociatedObject.CaretIndex)
                text = this.AssociatedObject.Text;
            else
            {
                //  Remaining text after removing selected text.
                string remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection;

                text = TreatSelectedText(out remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection)
                    ? remainingTextAfterRemoveSelection.Insert(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, e.Text)
                    : AssociatedObject.Text.Insert(this.AssociatedObject.CaretIndex, e.Text);
            }

            e.Handled = !ValidateText(text);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     PreviewKeyDown event handler
        /// </summary>
        void PreviewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmptyValue))
            {
                return;
            }


            string text = null;

            // Handle the Backspace key
            if (e.Key == Key.Back)
            {
                if (!this.TreatSelectedText(out text))
                {
                    if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart > 0)
                        text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
                }
            }
            // Handle the Delete key
            else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                // If text was selected, delete it
                if (!this.TreatSelectedText(out text) && this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length > AssociatedObject.SelectionStart)
                {
                    // Otherwise delete next symbol
                    text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, 1);
                }
            }

            if (text == string.Empty)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.Text = this.EmptyValue;
                if (e.Key == Key.Back)
                    AssociatedObject.SelectionStart++;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string text = Convert.ToString(e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

                if (!ValidateText(text))
                    e.CancelCommand();
            }
            else
                e.CancelCommand();
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Validate certain text by our regular expression and text length conditions
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"> Text for validation </param>
        /// <returns> True - valid, False - invalid </returns>
        private bool ValidateText(string text)
        {
            double number;
            if (!Double.TryParse(text, out number))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(number < Minimum)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (number > Maximum)
            {
                return false;
            }
            int dotPointer = text.IndexOf('.');
            // No point entered so the decimals must be ok
            if(dotPointer == -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (dotPointer > MaxInteger)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(text.Substring(dotPointer +1).Length > MaxDecimals)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Handle text selection
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true if the character was successfully removed; otherwise, false. </returns>
        private bool TreatSelectedText(out string text)
        {
            text = null;
            if (AssociatedObject.SelectionLength <= 0)
                return false;

            var length = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Length;
            if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart >= length)
                return true;

            if (AssociatedObject.SelectionStart + AssociatedObject.SelectionLength >= length)
                AssociatedObject.SelectionLength = length - AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;

            text = this.AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, AssociatedObject.SelectionLength);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ......>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ui:TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour MaxDecimals="2" 
                                         MaxInteger="1" 
                                         Minimum="{StaticResource Zero}" 
                                         Maximum="{StaticResource Ten}" />
        <ui:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```