# How can I filter keyboard number keys

Tags: wpf, mvvm, keypress

I wish to focus a specific `Textbox` and accept the key press only when the user presses a number key (1,2,3 etc.) otherwise I don't want to focus that `Textbox`...

Senario:

I have `ListView` (having a custom view) in a view. below the list view i have a `Textbox`.

Lets say `ListView` contains items numbered as 1, 2, 3, 33, 373 etc.

Now when I press a number key, lets say `Key 3`, the following action should occur:

1. Focus that Specific `TextBox`
2. Append the `TextBox` text with the number input
3. Select the item in the `ListView` with the same number as `TextBox.Text` has

My Xaml for what I tried

```
<ListView Name="lv"
              Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              View="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                             ElementName=viewComboBox}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding Path=Person.Name}"/>
    <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=TextSearch.Text,ElementName=lv}"></TextBox>
```

Nothing is displayed in the `TextBox` and I don't know how to handle numeric key press.

I need this and its bewildering using MVVM...

Any help in this regard would be great. And some guidance using code would be even better... Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

This logic is specific to view. Its fine if you put it in code behind. MVVM doesn't stop you from writing view specific code in code behind.

However if your religiously follow the 'no code behind' approach then you can create a [Behavior](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) and put all the code in that. Your behavior will be attached to listbox and will take textbox reference as property. It will listen to keydown event on listbox and add keys to textbox's text property.

You shouldn't really be having logic like this in ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM then **attached behavior** is the way to go ... http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/

1. Name you key press source element like `ListView` ...

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
      ....
   </ListView>
   ```
2. Declare and define an attached property of type `ListView` say `NumericKeyPressBehavior.FocusTarget`
3. The Source for this `FocusTarget` will be you `MyListView` and the behavior will be attached to your `TextBox`

   ```
    <TextBox local:NumericKeyPressBehavior.FocusTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyListView}" 
             .... />
   ```
4. In `NumericKeyPressBehavior.FocusTarget`'s dependency property changed event handler, handle the key press on the ListView and then based on if a numeric key was pressed, focus the target TextBox and also append the pressed key character to it.

   ```
   private static void  OnFocusTargetChanged(
       DependencyObject o, 
       DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var textBox = o as TextBox;
       var listView = e.NewValue as ListView;
       if (textBox != null && listView != null)
       {
           listView.KeyUp += 
            (o1, e1) =>
               {
                   var keyChar = GetKeyCharFromKeyCode(e1.Key);
                   if ("0123456789".Contains(keyChar.ToString()))
                   {
                       textBox.Focus();
                       textBox.Text += keyChar.ToString();
                   }
               }
       }
   }
   ```

`GetKeyCharFromKeyCode` is found here.... [C# How to translate virtual keycode to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char)

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for answering, let me try ill get back to you