# C# - How to translate from key to System.Windows.Forms.Key

Tags: c#, char, virtual, translate, keycode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How to translate virtual keycode to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char)

Basically I have a list of ascii characters that I need to have converted to System.Windows.Forms.Key (for use with PostMessage).  And it needs to work no matter what the keyboard/region/locale etc...

I know you can just cast it if it's from A-Z, but nothing else works.  Has anyone figured this out?

I'm talking about keys like [, ], <, >, etc... All the non-numeric and non-A to Z.

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: The noted duplicate has an answer that describes the `System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter` class that I believe does what you want, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You could pinvoke VkKeyScanEx(), pass InputLanguage.Handle

Comment: It's not a duplicate, unless just a [ is considered a virtual key code? I have a string/char I want, not necessarily a virtual char