# C# equivalent of WM_CHAR key press event?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, key, keypress

In C++ apps with `PeekMessage/TranslateMessage` you can invoke `WM_CHAR` messages that tell you which character has been pressed based on the current IME. This saves you from converting the keycode to the char code, which can be challenging for non-English IME's.

Does a .NET Window have the equivalent to the `WM_CHAR` windows messaging event? Can I aquire it somehow? Obviously I can listen for key events and [convert keycodes to char codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char) but it may not be as robust as windows doing it internally.

Comment: Don't really understand this.  The GUI components that can receive focus have KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyUp events?

Comment: Yes, but `WM_CHAR` is different from `WM_KEYDOWN` in that it provides the unicode char code instead of the typical keycode. I was looking for that information in .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event, and the [KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property of the supplied [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) instance.

Answer (score 1):

The closest approach to the `MFC` one is to use WndProc:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{

    if (m.Msg == WM_CHAR) //define WM_CHAR properly 
    {

    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```