# Can't use KeyCode in C#

Tags: c#, keycode

I'm trying to make it so that when the user pressed the PrintScreen button on their keyboard, a Messagebox appears.

I've looked a lot online and this code seems to be the standard of how to go about doing that.

**The issue is, I get an error saying,**

> System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition
>   for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PrintScreen)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: All right. Use the `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` events to access `KeyCode`.

Comment: Is it winform or WPF? Please include namespace and directives you have used.

Comment: @Dmitry I no longer get an error, but now nothing happens when I press the PrintScreen button on my keyboard

Comment: @jdphenix Stupid question, how can I know...

Comment: It's hardly a "stupid question". You would know by what references and using statements your project has.

Comment: @jdphenix http://i.imgur.com/2cZwR0G.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to translate virtual keycode to char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using KeyPress, use the KeyDown event. KeyPress event will only fire on printable characters, and PrintScreen is not one of them, so it only exposes the KeyChar property, while KeyDown or KeyUp will expose the KeyCode.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.PrintScreen)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped but when I press PrintScreen, no messagebox appears

Comment: Have you added the event through the window properties in the designer or just copypasted the code?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://i.imgur.com/6oVqxEa.png I believe I added an event

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to set KeyPreview to True

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 e.Key == Key.Snapshot
```

This will work on KeyUp and KeyDown events.