# Assigning multiple keys to a single command in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I built a calculator in WPF and would like to bind my keyboard keys to it.
Here is how I bind the NumPad0 key to my command. I'd also like to use D0 key to accomplish the same.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AddCharacterCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="0" Key="NumPad0"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Did you try adding another `KeyBinding`?

Comment: Haven't thought about that, thanks!

Comment: Any idea how I can access the "/" key on alfanumeric keyboard?

    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AddCharacterCommand}"     CommandParameter="/" Key="Divide"/>

this works for numpad only.

Comment: If you want to get the actual produced character then you will need to resort to some Win32Api calls to get the character behind the virtual key code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AddCharacterCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="0" Key="NumPad0,D0"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```